# Editing a form with SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

I've got an Artist page in SvelteKit. Its route looks like the following:

```
routes
    artists
        [slug]
            +page.server.js
            +page.svelte
        new
            +page.server.js
            +page.svelte
...
```

I've abstracted the form itself into a component called `ArtistForm.svelte`, for the purposes of this issue I'll show just one field:

```
<script>
    export let formData;
    export let mode = "new";

</script>

<form method="POST" use:enhance>
    {#if (mode !== "new") }
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value={ formData.id } />
    {/if}

    <!-- Row 1: name, type -->
    <div class="flex flex-row">

        <div class="basis-1/2 form-control w-full">
            <label class="label">
                <span class="label-text">Name <span class="required-field">*</span></span>
            </label>
            <input
                    name="name"
                    id="name"
                    type="text"
                    value={ formData?.name || "" }
                    class="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"/>
            {#if formData?.errors?.name}
            <label for="name" class="label">
                    <span class="label-text-alt text-error">{ formData?.errors.name[0]}</span>
            </label>
            {/if}
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex flex-row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{ mode == "new" ? "Save" : "Update" }</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

So in `artists\[slug]\+page.svelte` I've simply got:

```
<script>
    import ArtistForm from "../../../components/forms/ArtistForm.svelte";

    /* data returned from load function in +page.server.js */
    export let data;

    /* data returned from actions in +page.server.js */
    export let form;

</script>

<ArtistForm formData={data} mode="edit" />
```

and in `artists\new\+page.svelte` I've got:

```
<script>
    import ArtistForm from "../../../components/forms/ArtistForm.svelte";

    /* data returned from actions function in +page.server.js */
    export let form;

</script>

<ArtistForm formData={form} mode="new" />
```

So far so good. The issue comes when validating the data. So the action for new looks something like:

```
export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {

        const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());
        const artist = artistDTO(data);

        // if errors returned from building the DTO (validation errors) then return the object.
        if (artist?.errors && !emptyObject(artist.errors)) {
            return artist;
        }

        const response = await createArtist(artist);

        return {
            ...artist,
            "errors": response.errors,
        }
    }
};
```

If there are any validation errors it will return the fields plus the errors in an object.

For edit mode ([slug]) the action looks similar to the previous one.

When an error occurs on `new`, then the object returned from the action is assigned to `formData` so the entered fields are populated again plus there's gonna be an `errors` object from which errors will be displayed.

With the `new` form there are no issues.

But with the edit form (`[slug]`), I've got issues. When the page first loads then the object returned from the `load` method is assigned to `formData` so the form is populated with that data, but when the form is submitted, then if any errors are encountered and returned from the action, that object will be assigned to `form` and not to `data`, and `form` is not being passed into `ArtistForm`, but even if I decided to pass it, I'd need to know when to pull data from `data` and from `form`.

How can I achieve that? Not sure if the question is not clear, please let me know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could spread both form and data into the form component, something along the lines of:

```html
<ArtistForm formData={{...data, ...form}} mode="edit" />
```

Comment: Good thinking, i'll try that. What's the usual way to do it? I mean, how people usually do a edit page? they all have to face these same issues with `load` and `data` right?